# Using exec on a file in a different directory causes module import errors

Tags: python

I have 3 very simple scripts. The structure looks like this:

```
test.py
test_problem_folder
     test_problem_1.py
     test_problem_2.py
```

test.py:

```
import os

if __name__ == "__main__":
    filename = "./test_problem_folder/test_problem_1.py"
    exec(compile(open(filename, "rb").read(), filename, 'exec'), globals(), locals())
```

test_problem_folder/test_problem_1.py:

```
import test_problem_2
test_problem_2.test()
```

test_problem_folder/test_problem_2.py:

```
def test():
    print("Hello")
```

If I try to run test.py, I get the error:

*ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'test_problem_2'*

If I flatten the folder structure so that test_problem_* is the same directory as test.py, I don't get this problem. I figured the paths must be getting screwed up, so I tried os.chdir() to ./test_problem_folder, but that still gets the same error. What am I doing wrong? My real scenario is more complicated and I need to use exec instead of popen.

Comment: pretty sure you're missing an \_\_init\_\_.py

Comment: Didn't change anything.

Comment: Also might be that you need to tell it to look in the same dir for test_problem_2 by using `import .test_problem_2` (note the leading `.`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried your code, if i run `python test_problem_1.py` under `test_problem_folder`, everything is working properly.  Apparently, the Python path doesnt know anything about `test_problem_folder`

You can append abs path of `test_problem_folder` to your python path, then the module can be found, you dont have to have the `__init__.py` file under `test_problem_folder`

```
import os
import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":
    sys.path.append("/path/to/.../test_problem_folder")
    filename = "./test_problem_folder/test_problem_1.py"
    exec(compile(open(filename, "rb").read(), filename, 'exec'), globals(), locals())
```

Alternatively, you can append the directory of `test.py` to pythonpath, create `__init__.py` under `test_problem_folder`(this makes it as a python package other than directory) and then import test_problem_1 from module `test_problem_folder`

```
import os
import sys
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)))
import test_problem_folder.test_problem_1 as problem1

if __name__ == "__main__":
    pass
```

Comment: That works! Is this the only way though? In reality my code will be executing some python file given as an argument, and after running this a lot I don't want to pollute the path too much

Comment: Also I noticed that this works: sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(filename))
while this doesn't: sys.path.append(os.path.abspath(filename))

Comment: @user3715648 see my edit. the second method is more often used in python project, you append your project path to pythonpath